# Spring Data JPA save new Entity and get its all dependencies

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Im saving my entity to database via Spring Data Jpa save() method. This method returns saved entity object, however if Im saving new entity, then returned object isn't filled with for example @ManyToMany full entities.

As far I know, when Spring Data JPA save new entity, then it uses entityManager.persist() method, and if entity exist in database, then save() method uses entityManager.merge() method.

My question is, how to save new entity in database and get its full dependencies in one transaction?

I was trying to add some helper class, that my bean services extends, like:

```
public abstract class HelperPersistenceService<E extends AbstractEntity<I>, I extends Serializable> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public E saveWithMerge(E e) {
        if (e.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(e);
        }
        return entityManager.merge(e);
    }

}
```

and it works without @Transactional method. But now I got an excepton:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:278)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy778.persist(Unknown Source)
```

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a cascade=persist,merge on the many to many relationship?

The behaviour you're after requires this cascade to be present.